# How to selectively remove bar from bar plot?

Tags: r, bar-chart

I have the following data frame and code:

```
#example data
Correlation_task_persistence <-  c("-0.28", "-0.24", "-0.29", "-0.18", "-0.18", "-0.09", "0.01", "0.12")
Biv_A_task_persistence <- c("55%", "60%", "63%", "66%", "67%", "71%", "100%", "55%")
Biv_E_task_persistence  <- c("45%", "40%", "37%", "34%", "33%", "29%", "0%", "45%")
Correlation_activity <- c("0.24", "0.06", NA, "0.26", "0.10", "0.05", "0.03", "0.01")
Biv_A_activity <- c("72%", "54%", NA, "70%", "65%", "70%", "50%", "100%")
Biv_E_activity <- c("28%","46%", NA, "30", "35%", "30%", "50%", "0%")
age <- c("slope", "intercept", "36", "30", "24", "18", "12", "6")
df.new <- data.frame(Correlation_task_persistence, Biv_A_task_persistence,Biv_E_task_persistence, Correlation_activity, Biv_A_activity, Biv_E_activity, age )

#code to produce figure
df.new %>%
  mutate(across(Correlation_task_persistence:Biv_E_activity, 
                ~if_else(as.numeric(gsub("%", "", .x)) > 1,
                         as.numeric(gsub("%", "", .x, fixed = TRUE))/100, 
                         as.numeric(.x)))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(-c(age, contains("Correlation"))) %>% 
  mutate(Correlation = if_else(grepl("task", name),
                               Correlation_task_persistence, 
                               Correlation_activity),
         final_value = Correlation * value,
         name = gsub("_task", "", name)) %>%
  tidyr::extract("name", c("var","group"), regex = "(.*)_([^_]+)$") %>%
  group_by(age, group) %>%
  mutate(label = scales::percent(final_value / sum(final_value))) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  mutate(age = factor(age,
                      levels = c("0", "6", "12", "18", "24", "30", "36", "slope", "intercept"),
                      ordered = TRUE)) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = age, y = final_value, fill = var)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_text(aes(label = Correlation, group = age), 
            stat = 'summary', fun = function(x) sum(x) + 0.01 * sign(x), size = 3) +
  geom_text(aes(label = label), size = 3, position = position_stack(vjust = 0.5)) +
  scale_fill_grey(start = 0.475, end = 0.8, na.value = "red") +
  labs(y = "Correlation") +
  facet_wrap(~group)
```

Produces this figure:

[image]

I would like to alter my code to completely eliminate "age 36" (which no bar due to NA) from the plot for "activity" (left hand plot) so that the only ages displayed are 6, 12, 18, 24, 30 (i.e., there should be no gap between "age 30" and "slope"). I would like to do this without losing the "age 36" bar for the plot for persistence, because it obviously has data. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Add the argument `scales = "free_x"` to your `facet_wrap()` line, so it is `facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free_x")`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before you send the data to `ggplot`, filter out the NA values

```
filter(!is.na(final_value)) %>%
```

and then use free scales on the x-axis in your facet

```
facet_wrap(~group, scales = "free_x")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! When I do this, it removes the "age 36" bar from both the "activity" and "persistence" plots. How would I just remove the "age 36" bar for activity, but keep it for persistence.

Comment: @ericm I should have filtered on `final_value` since that's what you use for `y` in the plot. I updated the answer.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick! very helpful. Say, for instance, that instead of deleting the age 36 column for activity altogether, that I wanted to put an "NA" in that empty gap gap in the original figure. How would I go about doing this?

Comment: If you have a different question, you should start a new post. That is a completely different task.